# Defining a new command works selectively

Tags: macros, color

I have just created a new command that will print text in bold and blue using the following syntax

```
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\color{LHCblue}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

My full code is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\color{LHCblue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\definecolor{charcoal}{RGB}{34,34,34}
%Packages
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}%Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\mode<presentation>

%Theme commands
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
% \setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}% Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=charcoal}
% 
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%Pages at the bottom right corner
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=LHCblue,fg=white}
\title[\eng{Benchmarking} $^{nat}B(p,p)^{nat}B$]{\smallΈλεγχος Αξιοπιστίας Διαφορικών Ενεργών Διατομών Ελαστικής Σκέδασης Πρωτονίων σε Στόχο Φυσικού
Βορίου}
\author[Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος]{Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}
\institute[Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))]{Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item \blue{Διαφορική Ενεργός Διατομή} : Πιθανότητα αλληλεπίδρασης ανά μονάδα επιφάνειας ανά μονάδα στερεάς γωνίας
  \item $\dfrac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} = \dfrac{Y}{N \left(Q\Omega\right)}\;,        
        \uncover<2->{\begin{array}{ll}
         Y : & \text{ανιχνευόμενων σωματιδίων}\\
         N : &\text{ Πάχος του στόχου}\\
         Q : & \text{προσπίπτοντων σωματιδίων στον στόχο}\\
         \Omega : & \text{ Στερεά γωνία}
        \end{array}}
        $
  \item \blue{Μέτρηση} : Λεπτοί στόχοι(\eng{energy straggling})
  \item \blue{Γιατί} : \uncover<3->{\begin{enumerate}
                          \item Βασική Έρευνα (Πυρηνικά Μοντέλα)
                          \item Εφαρμοσμένη Έρευνα (Τεχνολογία Ημιαγωγών)
                          \item Πολιτιστική Κληρονομιά-Τέχνη (Αρχαιότητες, Πίνακες)
                         \end{enumerate}}
  \item \blue{Ορθότητα} : Πειραματικές ασυμφωνίες
  \item \blue{Αξιοπιστία} : Προσδιορισμός αβεβαιοτήτων
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that this command works only selectively and I cannot understand why. Look for instance the following image

[image]

Why is this happening? I suspect there is something wrong with my `newcommand` but I cannot find it... Any idea?

Comment: `\color` is like `\bfseries` and changes the colour of everything following you want `\textcolor{blue}{...}` which just changes the colour of its argument, like `\textbf{..}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Thank you very much for your comment! Would you mind posting an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you once again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\color` is like `\bfseries` and changes the colour of everything following: you want `\textcolor{blue}{...}` which just changes the colour of its argument, like `\textbf{..}`.

Comment: That, or put an additional pair of curly brackets around the color command, as in `\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{LHCblue}\textbf{#1}}}`

Comment: @JPi `\textcolor` is better, you can get weird spacing artifacts from `\color` (blame the author of the `color` package)

Comment: Thanks, but there are limits to what you can use as the argument to a `\textcolor` command that don't apply to the `\color` command, right?

Comment: @JPi but in this case the text has already been parsed as an argument to `\blue` and is going to be passed as an argument to `\textbf` so the differences are minimal